# KeyError: "Can't open attribute (Can't locate attribute: 'nb_layers')"

Tags: python, keras

I have a Python code that uses `Keras`. I didn't post the code because it is a bit long, and the issue seems not to be related to the code itself.

This is the error I'm having:

```
File "h5py\h5a.pyx", line 77, in h5py.h5a.open (D:\Build\h5py\h5py-2.7.0\h5py\h5a.c:2350)
KeyError: "Can't open attribute (Can't locate attribute: 'nb_layers')"
```

What could be the issue? Is it related to Keras? How can I solve this issue?

**EDIT 1**

The error seems to be related to this part of code:

```
# load VGG16 weights
    f = h5py.File(weights_path)

    for k in range(f.attrs['nb_layers']):
        if k >= len(model.layers):
            break
        g = f['layer_{}'.format(k)]
        weights = [g['param_{}'.format(p)] for p in range(g.attrs['nb_params'])]
        model.layers[k].set_weights(weights)

    f.close()
    print('Model loaded.')
```

Thanks.

Comment: this person had a similar problem https://github.com/hycis/bidirectional_RNN/issues/6

Comment: Could you post some of the surrounding code, particularly around line 77 or so?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I came across the link you posted and noticed that it is due a missing h5 file, but still couldn't get the point, and what this h5 would be

Comment: @KevinLondon I believe line 77 in the file h5a.pyx? I tried looking for this file but couldn't locate it.

Comment: I have added the part of code from the original program that I think is related to the error

Comment: Did you load model across different versions?

Comment: Hey did you find the solution for it? Please let me know how you solved it thanks!

Comment: Did you get a proper solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the weights file vgg16_weights_th_dim_ordering_th_kernels.h5 from https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases

This file is in Keras 2 format.

Comment: You might want to add a bit of explanation though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I solved it by building the vgg16 network where I needed it by adding this line.

```
 Vmodel = applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(3, img_width, img_height))
    print('Model loaded.')

    # build a classifier model to put on top of the convolutional model
    top_model = Sequential()
    top_model.add(Flatten(input_shape=Vmodel.output_shape[1:]))
    top_model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    top_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    top_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

    # note that it is necessary to start with a fully-trained
    # classifier, including the top classifier,
    # in order to successfully do fine-tuning
    top_model.load_weights(top_model_weights_path)

    # add the model on top of the convolutional base
    # model.add(top_model)
    model = Model(inputs=Vmodel.input, outputs=top_model(Vmodel.output))
```

So basically instead of creating a vgg16 Conv net of your own and loading the vgg16 weights into it. I created a vgg16 model and then added the last layers to the model. I hope this works for you.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently "nb_layers" refers to the number of layers, so instead you can use a work around.
In this case:

```
f = h5py.File(filename, 'r')
nb_layers = len(f.attrs["layer_names"])
```